# Disable autocorrect UITextView Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

How can I turn off auto correct and spell check in Swift? I found the following for objective-c, but nothing so simple for swift.

```
myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 55):

I'm answering all my own questions today... This seems to work.

```
textView.autocorrectionType = .no
```

Comment: Just in case, remember you can easily do it even via Interface Builder. If you use it of course.

Answer (score 15):

With Swift 3:

```
textView.autocorrectionType = .no
```

Answer (score 11):

[image]

choice connection -> set Default to No

Answer (score 3):

With swift 4.2: TextView and TextField

```
textView.autocorrectionType = .no
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

Answer (score 1):

To make more sense of this when coming from Obj-C to Swift and why you can do `.No` instead of `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo`, you can also do this:

```
myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
```

Comment: I agree with @chackle, it is easier to read, also Swift 3 version is lowercase no: myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the line of code that you posted, simply swap out the `myTextField` with the name of the field you wish to disable autocorrect functionality for, then after the = sign, just add `.No`